# How to chain api calls i.e. GETFIELD contact for fieldID after doing GET profile on profileID?

Tags: contacts, custom-fields, profile

I want to join the below api calls-

API 1

```
http://ec2-3-6-40-236.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/civicrm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Profile&action=get&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"profile_id":22}
```

RESULT 1

```
{

"is_error": 0,
"version": 3,
"count": 1,
"values": {
    "custom_64": "",
    "custom_65": "",
    "custom_66": "",
    "custom_46": "",
    "custom_47": "",
    "custom_48": "",
    "custom_62": "",
    "custom_50": "",
    "custom_51": "",
    "custom_63": "",
    "custom_53": "",
    "custom_54": "",
    "custom_55": "",
    "custom_56": "",
    "custom_57": ""
  }
}
```

API 2

```
http://ec2-3-6-40-236.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/civicrm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Contact&action=getfield&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"name":"custom_62","action":"get"}
```

RESULT 2

```
    {

    "is_error": 0,
    "version": 3,
    "count": 31,
    "values": {
        "id": "62",
        "label": "Relationship with Guardian",
        "headerPattern": "//",
        "title": "Relationship with Guardian",
        "custom_field_id": "62",
        "groupTitle": "Voter Details",
        "data_type": "String",
        "name": "custom_62",
        "type": 2,
        "html_type": "Radio",
        "default_value": null,
        "text_length": "255",
        "options_per_line": "2",
        "custom_group_id": "28",
        "extends": "Individual",
        "is_search_range": "0",
        "extends_entity_column_value": [
            "Voter"
        ],
        "extends_entity_column_id": null,
        "is_view": null,
        "is_multiple": "0",
        "option_group_id": "121",
        "date_format": null,
        "time_format": null,
        "is_required": null,
        "table_name": "civicrm_value_voter_details_28",
        "column_name": "relationship_with_guardian_62",
        "serialize": null,
        "where": "civicrm_value_voter_details_28.relationship_with_guardian_62",
        "extends_table": "civicrm_contact",
        "search_table": "contact_a",
        "pseudoconstant": {
            "optionGroupName": "relationship_with_guardian_20201110084841",
            "optionEditPath": "civicrm/admin/options/relationship_with_guardian_20201110084841"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried with this api call-

```
http://ec2-3-6-40-236.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/civicrm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Profile&action=get&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"profile_id":22,"api.Contact.getfield":{"name":"$value","action":"get"}}
```

But I got this error :(

```
    {

    "fields": [
        "name"
    ],
    "error_code": "mandatory_missing",
    "entity": "Profile",
    "action": "get",
    "is_error": 1,
    "error_message": "Error in call to Contact_getfield : Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: name"
}
```

Please help.

Comment: can you hardcode the value `custom_62` in the chain api call? If yes, `http://ec2-3-6-40-236.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/civicrm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Profile&action=get&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"profile_id":22,"api.Contact.getfield":{"name":"custom_62","action":"get"}}` should work. If not, i dont think it is possible in a single api call as the value you need to pass on the chained api is present in key and not value.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the `UFField` entity, not `Profile` ...  try:

```
entity=UFField&action=get&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"profile_id":22}
```

Then you can chain `getfield`:

```
entity=UFField&action=get&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,
"uf_group_id":22,
"api.Contact.getfield":{"action":"get","name":"$value.field_name"}}
```

That assumes the custom fields are for Contacts.